# Best open-source 3D game engine for a first person shooting game?

Tags: first-person-shooter, open-source

What is the best opensource 3D game engine suitable for 1st person shooting game? This engine should be script-able with lua.

Comment: Does it have to be open source? If I wanted to make a FPS my first choice would be UDK. It's what it does best (and not much more).

Comment: Why exactly the 'Lua' constrain? It would help us to give you a better suggestion.

Comment: Best with regards to what: rendering quality, hardware compatibility, highest fps rates, most consistent fps rates, ease of use? What kind of environment does the action take place: indoor, urban, outdoors? Do you need a physics engine, what will you use it for (racing, flying, or good-looking explosions)? What about sound? For competitive first-person shooters, directional sound and the ability to control attenuation is important. You need to be more precise about your goals and constraints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't told us your skill level. But, you can even try integrating Lua scripting functionality with any open source engine of your choice. There are libraries like Luabind & toLua++ for this.

After quick google search there are some interesting results,

1. [IrrLua](http://irrlua.sourceforge.net/) is a Lua binding for the Irrlicht 3D rendering engine. Last update : 08/23/06
2. [Scripting with LuaBind in Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Scripting+with+LuaBind+in+Ogre)
3. [Plugin development tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20171002103814/http://www.crystalspace3d.org/main/Luaplugin_tutorial) for integrating Lua scripting with Crystal Space Engine. But, I would suggest to stay away form this engine.
4. [BlendElf](http://web.archive.org/web/20140128105938/https://www.blendelf.com/) is a good choice.But, I don't think the developer isn't maintaining it any more.
5. If you see [Horde 3d](http://www.horde3d.org/home.html) feature list, you will see `Strong modularity and high abstraction through flat C-style DLL API (also makes it possible to use Horde3D from virtually any programming language)`, just like Leadwerks Engine.

*Many well/less known engines has Lua with it. Check it out.*

Answer (score 0):

Try http://blendelf.com/

Found it from here: [Easy to use cross-platform 3D engines for C++ game development?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21/easy-to-use-cross-platform-3d-engines-for-c-game-development/1959#1959)

Answer (score 0):

The [Doom 3 engine](http://www.iodoom3.org/) was recently Open Sourced under the GPL.

It doesn't have Lua support through. However it does have it's [own inbuilt c-like scripting language](http://www.modwiki.net/wiki/Scripting). If your working on your own game engine you can generally add it in yourself.

Answer (score 0):

[OctaForge](http://octaforge.org/) is:

- A 3D Game Engine, with Lua scripting and an easy to use in-game editor.
- A Game Platform, where you can find multiplayer games to play and upload your own games to as well.
- A place to find and upload game content to, from 3D models to textures to sounds.
- A community of game developers.

The above I lifted from their about page.  OctaForge is actually a fork of the popular [Sauerbraten](http://sauerbraten.org/) engine, with one of the goals replacing CubeScript with Lua.

Answer (score -1):

Ogre or Irrlicht 3D are good for C/C++ game programmers.

Answer (score -1):

The [Blender Game Engine](http://www.blender.org/) is pretty good for 3D games. It doesn't use Lua, but it uses Python, which is more comfortable to me (objects, classes, inheritance). It can definitely do FPS games, and supports GLSL shading. It also has the Bullet physics engine included, and, of course, is present inside of the 3D modeler, Blender.

Answer (score -1):

Open source AND with Lua scripting?

Well, that pretty much leaves [Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/), although frankly it isn't a game engine, it's a renderer/scenegraph.  You still need to plug in the other bits like IO, physics and audio, but plenty of options already exist.

If you drop the Lua requirement, your options open up a heck of a lot more, as does if you drop the Open Source requirement.

Answer (score -1):

[jMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/) is a very good open source 3D engine.

It runs on the JVM and you can also use [Lua on the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350771/lua-to-jvm-compiler) for scripting if that is a requirement.